# User activation query with if

Tags: php

Hi guys i have problem with my if conditional here is a query and script:

```
$sql_admin = "SELECT * 
                FROM users 
                WHERE username='$username' 
                AND hashed_password='$pass_admin' 
                AND lvl = 1 LIMIT 1";
$query_admin = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_admin);
$row_admin = mysqli_fetch_array($query_admin);
$id_admin           = $row_admin['id'];
$db_password_admin  = $row_admin['hashed_password'];
$lvl_admin          = $row_admin['lvl'];
$active_admin       = $row['active'];

if($pass_admin == $db_password_admin && $active_admin == 1) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id_admin;
    redirect_to("admin");
} elseif($pass_admin == $db_password_admin && $active_admin == 0) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Your acc is not activated.");';
    echo 'window.location.href="index";';
    echo '</script>';
} else {
    // something other
}
```

When i try only $pass_admin == $db_password_admin that´s work, but when i add ( && $active_admin == 0/1 it´s not working.

Thank´s for answers.

Comment: change 1/0 to '1' and '0'.... as mysql returns as string

Comment: what is dataType of active column?

Comment: For that code to work you must be Rolling Your Own password hashing. probably MD5() or SHA1() PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 2):

The error happens because you are using `$active_admin = $row['active'];` when you should use `$row_admin`  so change the line to

```
$active_admin = $row_admin['active'];
```

`$row` is never initiated but you used `$row_admin` to fetch data from your query

Comment: Thank you it´s work!! :)

Comment: You are welcome dude